# Log files are taking too much space and I can't delete\clear them

Tags: log, logrotate

After using Ubuntu for 2.5 months, my /var directory reached around **37 GB** or RAM while my `/` directory is all **50 GB** or RAM and the rest of space is for my `/home`.

I found that the following files are taking too much space in `/var/log`

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   14G Feb  2 07:46 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   13G Feb  2 07:46 ufw.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  5.9G Feb  2 07:46 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  451M Feb  2 23:53 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  451M Feb  2 23:53 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  441M Feb  2 23:51 ufw.log
```

Side question, what is `syslog` and `adm` ?!

Seeing `ufw` there, I checked it's configuration

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (full) <<<<<
```

So I set logging to low

```
$sudo ufw logging low
```

I read that logrotate should handle log rolling but it's configuration doesn't seem to handle the `/var/log` directory by default.

This is my `/etc/logrotate.conf` file content

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.conf 
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

I tried deleting the `log-file-name.log.digit` (i.e. `kernel.log.1`, `ufw.log.1`, `whatever.log.0`) but I couldn't. I tried `sudo echo '' > kernel.log.1` but I failed too. It always says

```
$ sudo echo '' > kern.log.1 
bash: kern.log.1: Permission denied
```

Restarting didn't help either. The logs directory wasn't cleared (I thought linux clears all the logs when it restarts, obviously I'm wrong), and I still couldn't clear\delete the mentions logs.

How can I clear those logs and make sure I never face this situation again ?

Using Ubuntu 13.10

**Answer**

```
sudo rm /var/log/*.1
```

But I **suspect** that what made my command faile is that I tried doing the same thing while I'm inside the directory `/var/log` (i.e. pwd = `/var/log`, then running `sudo rm kernel.1.log`). If someone faces the same situation, please try removing *.1 files while being in the `/var/log` directory (i.e. `cd /var/log;sudo rm*.1`) and report the results. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current logs are fine, still, those without `.1`. That is good, and you can remove it with:

```
sudo rm /var/log/*.1
```

Now you command doesn't work because of this:

```
sudo 'Everything here runs as root' > Everything here run as user
```

So if you wanted to do what you tried the correct would be:

```
sudo sh -c "echo '' > kern.log.1"
```

This is because the pipe opens a shell with the current user.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're saying !

Comment: Which part? The first is how to remove the logs, the second is explaining why your command did fail.

Comment: `rm` wouldn't work, it says `Permission denied`. By `sudo 'Everything here runs as root' > Everything here run as user`, you mean that sudo won't run in `/var/log` dir ? How can I make sure this doesn't happen again ? Is this a malfunction in my system ?

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `sudo rm /var/log/*.1` second, no, nothing wrong is with your system, just that is not how the shell works.

Comment: I'm not at my machine now, I'll do so when I am. Thank you.

Comment: Surprisingly the first command executed and deleted all *.1 files. I could swear I've already tried that ! Should this differ from specifying a file instead of a wildcard ? (Which what I was doing)

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana if the file didn't exist or was blocked, yes. It would throw an error.

Comment: Could the difference be the current directory where I tried to delete the files ? (i.e. pwd = /var/log) ?

Comment: Note also `> file` empties it.

Answer (score -2):

You can truncate logs without deleting by

```
cat /dev/null > file.log
```

But backup and archive log before execute command is useful.